# Can't Use 'window' Outside Activity In Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

Hello I **Don't** Want To Declare **The Same Function Over And Over**.
So I Wanted To Declare The Following Function **At The Top Level Of A File**.

```
package com.something.something

import android.view.View

fun enable_immersive_sticky_mode() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

But It Gives Me This Error **Unresolved Reference Window**.
But When I put It Inside An Activity It Works.
But I Want To Declare It **At The Top Level Of The File**.
Can Anyone Help Me Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass activity as argument

```
fun enable_immersive_sticky_mode(activity: Activity) {
    activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

when using in activity write `enable_immersive_sticky_mode(this)`

Comment: Awesome! As simple as it appears, I have spent more than 45minutes looking for this solution. Thanks @Manohar

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract BaseActivity class that extends Activity and to implement the sticky mode in the onCreate method:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     enable_immersive_sticky_mode()
   }
}
```

Then, You can extend every activity with the BaseActivity:

```
class ExampleActivity : BaseActivity()
```